# Interface issue when using Fruity Loops

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, music, acer-aspire, mouse-click

A simple but extremely frustrating issue.

I cannot enter notes into the piano roll (with a left-click) while at the same time playing notes on the keyboard. It’s as if playing the notes (by pressing keyboard keys) cuts out the click function of the mouse, at least on the piano roll.

I have looked through and tested different FL settings and switched between three different mouse drivers, all to no avail.

My laptop is an Acer E-571 running Windows 8.1 with FL studio 20.

Note: I recently re-installed windows with a disk mounted ISO and have since had an issue with the mouse where I can’t scroll without clicking first. Before the re-installation I was running FL 11 with no problems.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you reached out to their support desk, or posted on their forum? You might have more success over there. https://www.image-line.com/support/

Comment: I haven’t, although I will try. However I suspect that the issue may be rooted in the computer rather than the program since there are only a limited number of options in FL settings.